# Entity Framework Code First Create Database with tables initialized by Ids=value

Tags: c#-4.0

i use EF code first to create simple DataBase as a test and it created successfully,but
when i opened the tables created i got initialized rows with id=1 and no data .

i need to create empty database without any data initialized, can any help?

thanks.

//here are my code : 
    class People : DbContext 
    {
     public People() : 
           base(@"server=(local); database=People; trusted_connection=true;
                Security Info=True") 
       { 
         Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges()); 
       } 
     public DbSet Persons { get; set; }
    }
    class Person
    {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Age { get; set; }
     public string Sex { get; set; }
    }
//and this for running it: 
    class Program 
    { 
      static void Main(string[] args) 
      { 
        using (var db = new People()) 
         { 
           db.Persons.Add(new Person()); 
           db.SaveChanges(); 
           Console.Write("save complete"); 
         }
      }
    }

it just simple console one.
and when select from my created table person it retrieve id=1 and all other columns =null although i never try to enter any data just run code.if you run it you will get my point.

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You'll need to be much more clear about what you're asking and what you've already tried. Please include the code that initializes your database, and what data you're finding in it when you query.

Comment: Including code is suggested for most questions like this (though I'm not a C# programmer so I can't help you unfortunately)